# Inserting Rows of Data into an Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am just wondering how to programmatically insert values into a data base. I have created a Database and just want to create a large array of strings inside that database. Does anyone know how this could easily be accomplished.

Here is what I have so Far

```
public class GroupDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GroupTopics.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Topics_Table";
public static final String COL_1 = "Id";
public static final String COL_2 = "Topics";

public GroupDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TOPICS)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}
Where do I insert the data for the rows of the database?
Any Help is appreciated:)

Comment: Why ID and not _id? and what isn't working in your inserts?

Comment: The ID just because thats how I wrote it, I just don't know how to insert  the data into the rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following. Please check it out and see if it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513065/passing-an-array-of-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to insert data into a database At first you wil need a ContentValues which stores all your values.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Column_Name","Value");
values.out(etc);

and finally you will have to insert by getting a instance of your SqliteHelper


 database.insert("TableName",null,values);
```

null means that you can insert empty data to your table.

Comment: How do you insert all of the rows of values for one column

Comment: To do that you will have concatinate all the values to a single String and specify the column name and insert it like the above